# React / Typescript: Axios cross-origin POST request CORS error despite following all the common solutions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios, http-status-code-403

I'm running into a CORS error in my React / Typescript project when making a POST request with Axios. The app has a Node.js / Express back-end. I realize how common CORS errors are and I have looked at all the highest-rated posts about the issue, but I can't seem to resolve the error. I'm attempting to make a login POST request to a third party API (they require login validation to perform requests). Right now my POST request in the front-end looks like this:

```js
const headers = {
  crossDomain: "true",
  Accept: "*/*",
  Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Auth-Token",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
};

export const useKirbyLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "apiURL",
      {
        jsonData,
      },
      {
        headers: headers,
      }
    );
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Not all of these Headers options are configured at once - I've tried various configurations, headers with and without "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" or "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" (I don't think you're supposed to use these for requests but I tried anyway just in case), same with "Content-Type". I have also tried this with "Content-Type" set to "application/json."  I tried setting up Axios in a config file. None of that has worked. I've tried implementing the same things in my back-end, but receive a 403 error. In the back-end all CORS requests are enabled:

```
app.use(cors());
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx9iD.png)
[network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV24o.png)

I'm not sure what's going on and all the CORS solutions say the same things, but those solutions haven't worked for me.

EDIT:
I tried setting up the configuration in CORS on my server, but that is returning a 403 error still:

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

[error 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANBeF.png)

EDIT: I've contacted the API owner as I still haven't been able to get past the 403 error / CORS issue. Is it possible this problem is not on my end, or does anything in my code look incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

The API provider got back to me and confirmed it is indeed an issue on their end. In particular, it seems to be some issue with the localhost. I believe their API simply doesn't accept requests from a local host at this time. The (temporary) solution is to bypass the error using [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere).

```
export const useKirbyLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${apiURL}`,
      {
        jsonData,
      },
      {
        headers: headers,
      }
    );
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).